# Webpack's Hot Reload with a vagrant sandbox

Tags: vagrant, webpack, sandbox, livereload

Setting up an existing project with Webpack today. I develop of my local machine and the code runs on a vagrant based sandbox.

I would like to start using webpacks hot reload for sass, JS and React however that requires me to run the webpack-dev-server which only listens on at 'localhost:8080' where as my code runs on the sandbox at 'http://sandbox_ip'

is there anyway to get webpacks hot reload to trigger the reloading on the sandbox and not on its own server?